# Undo auto resizing for iPhone 5 screen after adding Default-568h@2x.png

Tags: iphone, size, screen, resolution, iphone-5

I followed the instructions in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12397309/1084932 to update my app for the new iPhone 5 screen size. Great, worked perfectly!

But, I am not quite ready to make this update and wish to roll back to the letterbox setup for now. I tried deleting Default-568h@2x.png to see if that would work, but my app still fills up the full iPhone 5 screen even without the Default-568h@2x.png file.

Anyone know how to undo the auto resizing for iPhone 5 after adding Default-568h@2x.png?

[EDIT] I have not tired with an iPhone 5 device, but my question is specifically with the simulator.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try doing `Product --> Clean` in Xcode

And delete the app from the phone and build again.

Sometimes the Default.png image gets cached

Comment: Thanks shabzco, this was half correct. I fixed my own issue. You need to completely reset content and settings in the simulator, for both iOS 5.x and 6.0, and then restart the simulator. Then, do a Product --> Clean as @shabzco suggested. Guess the simulator and product needed a real thorough cleaning.

Comment: This is probably related to my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434122/iphone-app-upgrade-and-moved-xibs-nibs-leads-to-stale-resources, it's likely that the old Default-568h@2x.png was stale in there even though it had been removed from the project.  The good news is that it wouldn't have made it to the app store, but would have stuck around on any devices or simulators you were testing on from Xcode.

Comment: One thing I found helpful was to check for the warning "Missing ... Retina 4 launch image"