# My app will not letter box and objects can be moved outside of the game environment

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios6, iphone-5

Hi I am working on an app and it was almost finished until I got my iPhone 5 and tested my app on this and now it shows a large white rectangle at the bottom of the screen (which looks like the extension of the screen) I assumed the app would automatically letterbox its self so this would not appear and the objects that you can move freely on the screen at go over this white rectangle which makes the game useless.

is there some setting on xcode that have to be published for this.

or if possible is there some simple code i can add to determine weather the ios devise is iphone 5 or 4s and lower to then add a different object screen?

[image: Image showing issue]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing that tells iOS whether to use the larger screen size is the presence of a `Default-568h@2x.png` file (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution/12397309#12397309)).

If you have added such a file (which may be added automatically if you drag an image into the iPhone 5 launch image section of your project's settings in Xcode) then that's why it's giving you full screen.

If that is the case, once you remove that file you'll need to clean your project (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12536486/undo-auto-resizing-for-iphone-5-screen-after-adding-default-568h2x-png)).

However, if you've never added a `Default-568h@2x.png` file and it's still giving you full screen, then I'm afraid I don't know what is wrong :(

Comment: hey, no i have never added such a file not even added a defult at the target screen for the larger 4" display

Comment: i take my last statment back after looking deep into my resorses i find the dreaded Default-568h@2x.png file removed and cleaned worked great cheers