# Black lines on iPhone5 with old apps

Tags: iphone, ios, xib, iphone-5

I got an old app, wich is compatible with 3.5 inch displays, like on iPhone4S and older.
This is app's screen:
[image]

When i tried run this app on iPhone5 simulator it looks really bad!
[image]

Apple promis that all old apps will appear with black lines on top and bottom! How should i do it? I don't want to refactor all my code from xib files.

Thanks

Comment: I think you might have used `autolayout`.

Comment: Those are scrollbars.  For whatever reason, your view is slightly larger than the window.

Comment: Have you tested it in device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you add launch images (like `Default-568h@2x.png`) for your app? This will signal iOS to stretch the app to the full display. Apps without will be displayed with black borders at the top and bottom.

Also see this question + answer on how to fix this:
[Undo auto resizing for iPhone 5 screen after adding Default-568h@2x.png](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12536486/474896)