# New app to run on iPhone 5 like the old apps do (centered in screen with 2 void areas above and below)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib, iphone-5, screen-size

I made an app for the iPhone 4 and the screen size is good and all is well... when I run the app on the iPhone 5 though the app isn't centered in the middle of the screen like off of my old apps were, it is stretched to fill the screen and there is a lot of messed up stuff going on. How can I make it just center in the screen with a black bar above and below it like old apps do that run on iPhone 5's, also will Apple reject my app for doing so after the fact that iPhone 5's are now released?

Comment: Is this a new app? Why wouldn't you make it work on the full 4" screen? Your users will like you better if you do.

Comment: @rmaddy I have way too many calculations to re-adjust everything in time for my deadlines. No user experience will be lost without the app working in full screen, luckily. :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12536486/undo-auto-resizing-for-iphone-5-screen-after-adding-default-568h2x-png

Comment: Wonderful, all that was needed was to delete the `Default-568h@2x.png` file that comes with the app (not just removing the reference but actually deleting) then cleaning the project and AND deleting the current build of the app off of the phone. Worked like a charm! Thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was already mentioned as the solution in the comments by rmaddy and I:

just deleting `default-568h@2x.png` and removing the app from the device and doing a clean build is all that was needed to "fix" the problem.

Answer (score 0):

By deleting default-568h@2x.png (reference and file) from project. and also deleting the app from simulator and doing a "clean" and then "build" it will work. But there will be a warning for deleted image.