# Prevent UIViewController loading stale XIB from app bundle

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController subclass in a shipping app whose UI has historically been loaded from a XIB file.

In order to resolve some iOS 7 compatibility problems, I've had to switch to building this screen programatically, hence the XIB is no longer required and I've deleted it from the project and done a clean build in Xcode.

However, when installing the new build over the top of the version on the App Store, I'm ending up with a double UI - it looks like the residual XIB file which will still exists in the app bundle for upgraded versions is getting loaded as well as my programatically-created version.

Does anyone know how to stop a UIViewController subclass from loading a stale XIB and **only** creating the view programatically?

I've tried temporarily commenting out the call to `[super initWithNibName: nil bundle nil]` in my `initWithNibName:bundle:` implementation (I know this is a bad thing to do - just trying things out to understand the problem better), but this has not helped.

Comment: Why not rename the class?

Comment: left the XIB blank and set all components programmatically else you have to change you UIViewController to UIView.

Comment: Thanks guys, but I've found a solution (see below), but StackOverflow won't let me mark my own solution as the answer for another two days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving my programatic view creation code from `viewDidLoad` to `loadView` solved the problem; it seems implementing this method prevents the runtime from going looking for a XIB to load.

Comment: Make sure that you call `[super loadView]` first.

Comment: I take that back, Apple's docs say never to call `[super loadView]`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use initWithNibName and just create your view like this :

```
myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
```

Next, in your `viewDidLoad` you can create all your UI elements programatically.

Comment: Jordan - thanks for your answer; appreciate the offer of help. However you should always call your super classes' designated initializer, otherwise Bad Things (tm) happen. It might appear to work, but you are leaving yourself open to all kinds of potential random breakage if you don't.

Comment: @AndrewEbling the designated initializer thing only applies when writing an init method. He's not calling init on the super object here. Creating a view controller using init is absolutely fine.

Comment: @jrturton - thanks for clearing that up. It's been a long, long time since I read/learned about designated initialisers.