# HTML File Localization

Tags: html, ios, localization

I have successfully done localization of my HTML file. However, when I am trying with pseudo-localization [By changing language of simulator], it still shows a English version of HTML file.

So I track down the issue. One of my HTML file is working fine with all languages.
While fetching it with following code

`NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"about" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:nil forLocalization:[userPrefered objectAtIndex:0]];`

I am getting htmlFile path as -

/Users/Tushar/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F607AED8-BC01-48DE-B3D0-BC3C028BBB23/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/8AB487BF-3CC2-4FC9-8371-D3AAB4955D05/APP_NAME.app/hu.lproj/about.html

But, for another HTML file I am getting htmlFile path as -

/Users/Tushar/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F607AED8-BC01-48DE-B3D0-BC3C028BBB23/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/8AB487BF-3CC2-4FC9-8371-D3AAB4955D05/APP_NAME.app/disclaimer.html

Clearly, if you observe, 'hu.lproj/' is missing in second htmlFile file path, which is creating this issue. I am not getting why is this happening.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I solved this issue. In case if anybody else face the same issue. I dont know why, but the method,

```
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"about" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:nil forLocalization:[userPrefered objectAtIndex:0]];
```

is not working properly.

So I changed the method to

```
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"about" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:[[userPrefered objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"lproj"]];
```

And now its working absolutely fine.

Hope this would help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Are your sure the `hu.lproj/disclaimer.html` file is also available in the .app package?

There was [a long standing bug with XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434122/iphone-app-upgrade-and-moved-xibs-nibs-leads-to-stale-resources) not always copying new or updated resources into the compiled app package properly. I haven't worked with XCode in a while, but maybe that is still a thing? To be sure, inspect the .app file in the build/Debug folder, right click and select "Show Package Contents" and see if `hu.lproj/disclaimer.html` exists there.

Comment: Yes, 'hu.lproj/disclaimer.html' is present there in .app package contents. But one more interesting thing is, '.app' package also contains 'disclaimer.html' file, outside of any '.lproj' folder.
And that is why I am getting htmlFile path as -

'/Users/Tushar/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F607AED8-BC01-48DE-B3D0-BC3C028BBB23/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/8AB487BF-3CC2-4FC9-8371-D3AAB4955D05/APP_NAME.app/disclaimer.html'

 Which is a mystery for me, how this file is getting created ?